# With NestJS and TypeORM, can I get away with passing an ID to a @ManyToOne relation?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, relation, many-to-one

I'm using NestJS 10 and typeorm 0.3.17.  I hvae this entity ...

```
@Entity()
export class Card {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;
  
    @ManyToOne(type => User)
    @JoinColumn({name: 'owner_id', referencedColumnName: 'id'})
    author: User;

    ...
}
```

and its corersponding DTO ...

```
export class CreateCardDto {
    author: User,
    category: Occasion;
    title: string;
    frontImg: Buffer;
    frontImgAltText: string;
    backImg: Buffer;
    backImgAltText: string;
}
```

I have a controller method where I set my user based on what is stored in the request object ...

```
  @Post()
  async create(@Req() req: Request, @Body() createCardDto: CreateCardDto) {
    const userId = req.user['sub'];
    const user = await this.usersService.findById(userId);
    createCardDto.author = user;
    return this.cardsService.create(createCardDto);
  }
```

and in turn save the object in the service method ...

```
  async create(createCardDto: CreateCardDto): Promise<Card> {
    return this.cardRepository.save(createCardDto);
  }
```

What I wanted to know is in the controller method, I look up the user object using the ID

```
const user = await this.usersService.findById(userId);
```

but this seems a little wasteful since I only need to save the ID in my target object, but because of the "@ManyToOne" relationship, I define a "User" object in the entity.  Is there a more efficient way to do this to save me making an unnecessary database lookup call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just use: `createCardDto.author = { id: userId }` and save it

Comment: but you should findOneByOrFail first to prevent relationship violation in case userId not exist in db

Comment: To ask the dumb question -- why would I need to do this if I have a PostGres constraint "FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES "user"(id)"?  This would cause the INSERT to fail if the user ID didn't exist, no?