# NestJs create relation given the id

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, many-to-one

I have 2 entities: `User` and `Article`. One article is created by one user, but one user may create many articles. Their respective entities are defined like this:

```js
export class Article {
    id?: string; // Optional to allow db to generate id
    // ...
    user?: User;
}

export class User {
    id?: string;
    username: string;
    password: string;
}
```

I have separated the entities from their schemas following the [NestJs Documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#separating-entity-definition).
The `Article` should have a column `userId` that is related to the `User`. This is defined in the `relations` part of the schema. I do not specify an `userId` column, only in the relations.

```js
export const ArticleSchema = new EntitySchema<Article>({
    name: 'Article',
    target: Article,
    tableName: 'Article',
    columns: {
        id: {
            type: String,
            primary: true,
            generated: 'uuid',
        },
        // ...
    },
    relations: {
        user: {
            type: 'many-to-one',
            target: 'User',
            nullable: false,
            joinColumn: {
                name: 'userId',
            },
        },
    },
});
```

In my controller, I receive a `CreateArticleDto`:

```js
export class CreateArticleDto {
    // ...
    @IsUUID()
    userId: string;
}
```

I know that TypeORM, by default, creates a column `relatedEntityId` when we specify a relation and pass the `entity`, in my case, `user: User`. However, in my controller, I only have access to the `userId`. I want to create an `Article` without having to search for the `User` entity.

Currently, I have to create an empty user (with only the id) to pass it to the service,  then search for the user with that `id` and save it in the Article in order to save an Article to the database:

**Controller**

```js
const article: Article = {
    ...createArticleDto,
    user: {
        id: createArticleDto.userId,
        username: '',
        password: '',
    },
};
const result = await this.articleService.create(article);
```

**Service**

```js
async create(article: Article) {
    const user = await this.userService.getById(article.user.id);
    article.user = user;
    const result = await this.articleRepository.create(article);
    return result;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Ideally, using only the userId to create a new Article.

Comment: My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77327161/with-nestjs-and-typeorm-can-i-get-away-with-passing-an-id-to-a-manytoone-relat?rq=2). However, the solution given there cannot be implemented in my codebase due to the typing of User within an Article requiring more attributes, it could be used as a last resort but it does not look like the intended way.

Answer (score 0):

After more research I was able to find this [obscure documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/decorator-reference.md#relationid).
Although it seems like a workaround, I do not think there is another way of doing this.

There is a [discussion](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/536) that started on 2017 in the typeorm repo about this feature. Repeating the `relationEntityId` in the schema and entity feels wrong and kind of weird, but it is better than doing more database lookups than necessary.

Comment: Doing this has introduced a new bug in my code. IDK if it's typeorm's fault or mine: [unsolved related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77471943/nestjs-typeorm-null-value-in-column-userid-of-relation-article-violates)