# NestJs / Typeorm - null value in column "userId" of relation "Article" violates not-null constraint

Tags: postgresql, null, nestjs, typeorm, many-to-one

I have 2 entities: `Article` and `User`. I defined a `manyToOne` relation in article, one user may have many articles. I also defined both the relation and the relationId column in the article schema:

```js
relations: {
    user: {
        type: 'many-to-one',
        target: 'User',
        nullable: false,
        joinColumn: {
            name: 'userId',
        },
    },
},
relationIds: {
    userId: {
        relationName: 'user',
    },
},
```

I receive a `CreateArticleDto` convert it to an `Article` entity with an `userId` field.
I even logged the value right before sending it to typeorm `save`, this was the result:

```js
{
  title: 'article title',
  description: 'cool article',
  link: 'www.link-to-article.com',
  author: 'the guy who wrote',
  userId: '1134b652-fadb-44c9-8a5f-0f73bf6ac18f'
}
```

Showing that the `userId` is not null, but I still get the following error:
`ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] null value in column "userId" of relation "Article" violates not-null constraint`

How can I fix this?